# Compactly supported test functions

Tags: functions, compactness, distribution-theory

I am considering the test function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(\pi x)},$$
My question is whether the test function is compactly supported? I am aware of the definition of compact support, namely:
"A function has compact support if it is zero outside of a compact set".
I believe the domain of this function is: $$x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{\pm\frac{n}{2},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\},$$
This is a closed and bounded set, so also compact. But how do I show that this function is zero outside of this set? as it surely takes no value outside of this set? I'm fairly sure it is compactly supported, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{\pm\frac{n}{2},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is not bounded, hence not compact !

Comment: This is far from being with compact support, since $f(x)$ is nowhere equal to $0$.

Comment: The function is not smooth, so cannot be used as a test function.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. This test function was given to me in the context of this integral: $I=\int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{\delta\left(\left[x-3\right]\left[x^2-4\right]\right)}{\cos(\pi x)}.$ I solved it assuming compact support using composition rules(which as you say is clearly incorrect). However, I got $\frac{1}{20}$ as my answer. I have put this into wolfram and they have given the same result as I calculated incorrectly( but theirs somehow using the Heaviside function). Is this a coincidence that I got the same answer as wolfram? and do you have any ideas what method wolfram uses?

Comment: @George. What rule do you refer to with "composition rules"?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(g(x))dx=\sum_i \frac{f(x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|},$ where the summation is over the ith root of $g(x)$. This of course should only hold for a suitable, smooth test function (which $\frac{1}{\cos(\pi x)}$ is not. However, I have gotten an answer using this incorrect method, that wolfram agrees with.

Comment: The method does not require that $f$ has compact support. It is enough that $f$ is smooth on a neighborhood of the support of $\delta \circ g$ and it is.

Comment: By the way, the support of $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\pm\frac{n}{2},n\in\mathbb{N}\},$ but $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{\frac{2n+1}{2},n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Fred , @OlivierMoschetta and @Chrystomath this test function is not compactly supported. However, this function can be used in the context of the composition integral, as per @md2perpe 's comment as it is smooth on a neighbourhood of the support of $\delta \circ g$
(I posted this as answer just so the thread can be closed)